Programatically extract figure number from bookdown (Global variable for figure number)
I use bookdown to create reports and to increase data traceability and to allow others to easily use the data in the future. I would like to export the raw data alongside these reports. Therefore I am looking for a way to extract the 'figure number' that bookdown is generating in the output (html, word, pdf) so I can make an excel workbook with a sheet containing the raw data for each figure in the report. I would like to name these sheets using the same figure numbers bookdown creates.
Does anyone know what the variable name bookdown creates for the figure number and if we have access to it in R or does all that happen post R? If so what is the variable name?
For example: create a data.table to be used in a plot, plot it with ggplot, and also export it as a named sheet to excel. The sheet name will be "figure_name" as in the following example.
The following code: will create an excel workbook named "test.xlsx" with the worksheet named "figure_number".
library(data.table)  ## data.table
library(ggplot2)     ## plotting
library(openxlsx)    ## export to excel named woksheet


kPlot <- as.data.table(iris)
kPlot <- kPlot[,.(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width)]

ggplot(kPlot, aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Sepal.Width))+
  geom_point()

write.xlsx(x = list(figure_name = kPlot), file = "test.xlsx")

What I would like to do is extract the figure_name that matches the output as the worksheet name. (Ie if bookdown calls this figure 1.6 in the output file then the worksheet would be named figure 1.6.
Thanks!
